# How to auto increment INSERT INTO in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data from table A to table B with query

```
INSERT INTO tableB(Status, UserIn, TableBID, Name)
    SELECT 
        'Active',
        UserInput,
        COALESCE(MAX(TableAID),0)+1,
        Name
    FROM 
        tableA
```

But I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'TableAID'.

Here my TableA:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA  
(
    Status VARCHAR(10),
    UserInput VARCHAR(25),
    TableAID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(32)
)
```

And my tableB

```
CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    Status VARCHAR(1),
    UserIn VARCHAR(25),
    TableBID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(32)
)
```

Comment: Can you provide DDL of table A?

Comment: question edited @streetturtle

Comment: what do you want to do specifically?

Comment: Based on your question, your error is because you don't actually have a column called `TableBID` in `TableB`. Your DDL says you do though. You need to post the correct SQL and DDL because it is currently contradictory. You also need to post what you're actually trying to do at a higher level, i.e. load these rows into this table, generating a new id

Comment: After editing your query, do you still get same error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are selecting from tableA, which doesn't have a TableBID column. As I understand you are trying to get the max tableBID and increment it by one for each row you insert from tableA, you could try:

```
INSERT INTO tableB(Status,UserIn,TableBID,Name)
SELECT 
'Active',
UserInput,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 1))+ (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(TableBID),0) FROM tableB ),
Name
FROM 
tableA
```

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 1))` will return an incrementing number starting from 1 for each row you are inserting from tableA.

Comment: i already edited the question. but this answer is acceptable! thank for the reply!

Comment: The usual approach is to create an `identity` column in the target table but this is certainly ample, as long as you don't run the query twice.

Comment: An awesome solution.

Answer (score 4):

Two things I noticed. One it looks like for `Status` you are trying to insert 5 characters of data into a `varchar(1)` column. Maybe you should change the column length or the data you are inserting.

Second, you have multiple columns alongside an aggregate function `MAX` without using a `GROUP BY` or `OVER`.

Comment: thank you correcting me, and thank you for the advice... :)